# How to get Main Array with the Object when filtering a Sub array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have this array of data, where when I filter the sub-array the `orderedItems` object key is only filtered not the whole data, This is my code.

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: 6,
    orderedItems: [ { name: "Product A", vendor: 2 }, { name: "Product B", vendor: 2 }, { name: "Product B", vendor: 2 } ]
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    orderedItems: [ { name: "Product Aaa", vendor: 1 }, { name: "Product Bbb", vendor: 1 }, { name: "Product Ccc", vendor: 2 } ]
  }
];
const userId = 1;

const filteredData = data.map(({ id, orderedItems }) => {
  return {
    id: id,
    orderedItems: orderedItems.filter(({ vendor }) => vendor == userId),
  };
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(filteredData, null, 2));
```

**Result:**

```
[
  {
    "id": 6,
    "orderedItems": []
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "orderedItems": [ { "name": "Product Aaa", "vendor": 1 }, { "name": "Product Bbb", "vendor": 1 } ]
  }
]
```

**Expected Result:**

```
[
  {
    "id": 5,
    "orderedItems": [ { "name": "Product Aaa", "vendor": 1 }, { "name": "Product Bbb", "vendor": 1 } ]
  }
]
```

The filter works but only for the orderedItems object key, I wanted the id too outside of the array to be filtered too. Is there any way to do this?, If there any clarification or explanation you need please comment down below. Thanks

Comment: Please provide a clear example with a ``userId`` and expected output

Comment: ok I will edit it right away

Comment: I have edited the question already and specified what I wanted

Comment: So you want to filter out the resulting objects with no ``orderItems``?

Comment: Yes, something like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to iterate over the list and in each iteration, compute the filtered orders of the current item, and in case it's not empty, add it to the accumulator with the current `id`:

```js
const 
  data = [
    { id: 6, orderedItems: [ { name: "Product A", vendor: 2 }, { name: "Product B", vendor: 2 }, { name: "Product B", vendor: 2 } ] },
    { id: 5, orderedItems: [ { name: "Product Aaa", vendor: 1 }, { name: "Product Bbb", vendor: 1 }, { name: "Product Ccc", vendor: 2 } ] }
  ],
  userId = 1;

const filteredData = data.reduce((filteredItems, { id, orderedItems }) => {
  const itemFilteredOrders = orderedItems.filter(({ vendor }) => vendor == userId);
  if(itemFilteredOrders.length > 0) {
    filteredItems.push({ id, orderedItems: itemFilteredOrders });
  }
  return filteredItems;
}, []);

console.log(JSON.stringify(filteredData, null, 2));
```

Another way to complete your approach would be to filter the resulting list by the length of `orderedItems`:

```js
const 
  data = [
    { id: 6, orderedItems: [ { name: "Product A", vendor: 2 }, { name: "Product B", vendor: 2 }, { name: "Product B", vendor: 2 } ] },
    { id: 5, orderedItems: [ { name: "Product Aaa", vendor: 1 }, { name: "Product Bbb", vendor: 1 }, { name: "Product Ccc", vendor: 2 } ] }
  ],
  userId = 1;

const filteredData = data
  .map(({ id, orderedItems }) => ({
    id,
    orderedItems: orderedItems.filter(({ vendor }) => vendor == userId)
  }))
  .filter(({ orderedItems }) => orderedItems.length > 0);

console.log(JSON.stringify(filteredData, null, 2));
```

Comment: Thanks for answering , it worked just what I needed, thanks for also putting options for the uses :))

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to go through and keep track of each match in the `data` array. And [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter out the items of `.orderedItems` that don't pass the condition.

**Full code:**

```js
const data = [ { id: 6, orderedItems: [ { name: 'Product A', vendor: 2, }, { name: 'Product B', vendor: 2, }, { name: 'Product B', vendor: 2, }, ], }, { id: 5, orderedItems: [ { name: 'Product Aaa', vendor: 1, }, { name: 'Product Bbb', vendor: 1, }, { name: 'Product Ccc', vendor: 2, }, ], }, ];

const userId = 1;

let res = data.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  let passed = obj.orderedItems.filter((subObj) => subObj.vendor === userId);
  if (passed.length) acc.push({ ...obj, orderedItems: passed });
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, It worked I already upvoted the question

Answer (score 0):

You may use the method filter to select all the ids matching the userId and then proceed with your code:

````js
const filteredData = data.filter(el => el.id === userId).map(({ id, orderedItems }) => {
  return {
    id: id,
    orderedItems: orderedItems.filter(({ vendor }) => vendor == userId),
  };
});```
````